# Can you use fix via do.call?

Tags: r, do.call

I have some code where it is more convenient to call `fix` via `do.call`, rather than directly.  Any old data frame will work for this example:

```
dfr <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = letters[1:5])
```

The obvious first attempt is

```
do.call("fix", list(dfr))
```

Unfortunately, this fails with

```
Error in fix(list(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)) : 'fix' requires a name
```

So, we give it a name:

```
do.call("fix", list(dfr = dfr))
```

This time it fails with

```
Error in is.name(subx) : 'subx' is missing
```

For the record, `edit` doesn't work either.

```
dfr <- do.call("edit", list(dfr = dfr))
```

Can anyone think of a sensible workaround, please?

EDIT: Upon reflection, I'd forgotten that `fix` always dumps its answer into the global environment, which is fine for test examples, but not so good for use with functions.  Joshua's excellent workaround doesn't extend to use with `edit`.

For bonus points, how do you call `edit` via `do.call`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `substitute`, which is also useful for when you want to use variable names as labels.

```
do.call("fix",list(substitute(dfr)))
```

**Edit for clarity**

It is easier to see how this works by using the  `call` command:

```
> call("fix",dfr)
fix(list(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), y = 1:5))
> call("fix",substitute(dfr))
fix(dfr)
```

Thus when you use `substitute` the command that is being created uses the name of the symbol rather than the evaluated symbol. If you wrap an `eval` around these expressions you see that the first example gives the same error you encountered, and the second example works as expected.

After reading hadley's link it becomes clearer what is being evaluated:

```
> as.name("dfr")==substitute(dfr)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I find that any occasion I use `substitute` has typically been preceded by an extended session of programming-induced tourettes.  If anyone knows of a simple explanation of how and when to use it, I'd be grateful.

Comment: @hadley: Thanks for the link; it's much clearer than the R language manual.

Comment: You're better off testing for equality with `identical()`

Comment: I think it's better to use `as.name` here because substitute does so many different things so it makes it hard to figure out what's going on.  But I really like your explanation now.

Answer (score 3):

The first error gives you a hint.  This works:

```
do.call(fix,list("dfr"))
```

You would still get the same error on your second try even if you used `dfr="dfr"` because the named list needs names of the arguments to `what` (the function).  So your second try should be:

```
do.call(fix,list(x="dfr"))
```

Comment: @Richie: try James' answer too, since it's more R-like.

Comment: @Joshua: Marking James as the official answer, on account of how it solves the `edit` problem too, but remind me I owe you an extra upvote for that excellent speedy response.

Comment: @Richie: no worries; it's the better answer.

Comment: No, this is the better answer because it correctly interprets the input to `fix`.

Comment: @hadley `fix` takes on input either a name or a character string, so surely both answers are correctly interpreting the input

Comment: @James: The documentation says that `fix` takes a name or character string, but it doesn't really: neither `x <- "mtcars"; fix(x)` or `fix(as.name("mtcars"))` work - I think because the documentation is using name in the non-technical sense.  The conclusion is that you're both right, but fix is a horrible function.